# Is this is dead lock? Why does executing the program say it is a dead lock?

Tags: go, deadlock

When I run this program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var mu = new(sync.Mutex)

func f2() {
    mu.Lock()
    fmt.Println("call f2...")
}

func main() {
    go f2()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    mu.Lock()
    fmt.Println("get lock in main")
}
```

I get this output:

```
call f2...
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/-P3CuXyaqBd).

As we know there are four condition to have dead lock, one is `Hold and wait or resource holding` which require there are at least two kind of resource to get, but here is only one resource.

So is this a dead lock or not?

I know quit a lot of concurrence programming. It just in this case it is only `f2()` not release lock, and that is not a deadlock as [wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Comment: The first sentence of that page says "In concurrent computing, a deadlock is a state in which each member of a group is waiting for another member" which describes the situation exactly.

Comment: and in Necessary conditions part it says 
> Hold and wait or resource holding: a process is currently holding at least one resource and requesting additional resources which are being held by other processes.

Comment: so the reason explain will be `necessary conditions` is for linux process model. not for goroutine model.

Comment: All four conditions are met. "Process" in the article doesn't (necissarily) mean CPU process. It means process in the general sense.

Comment: could you kindly tell why `Hold and wait or resource holding` is met? f2 and main is not ask for any other resource. and main even not hold any resource

Comment: `mu.Lock()` is how the "hold and wait" requirement is met.

Comment: @petelin The resource here is the lock. Getting the lock is `mu.Lock()`. Both `main()` and `f2()` tries to do that, but the lock is a "thing" which can only be locked once. It can only be locked again if someone unlocks it first. But nobody unlocks it in your code.

Comment: Go's definition of a deadlock is right there in the error message: "all goroutines are asleep". Wikipedia's definition of a deadlock is irrelevant.

Comment: There is absolutely zero point in discussing whether the Wikipedia definition of deadloack apllies to this deadlock or. You have a deadlock! If you think Wikipedia's definition does not apply: Change the definition on WP. This is pointless.

Comment: I suspect there's an honest, legitimate question in here, about the nature of a deadlock. But the OP's rude comments, coupled with poor English (which I do not hold against the OP at all, for the record) has turned it into an adversarial question.

Answer (score 3):

**Note beforehand:**  A "goroutine deadlock" (this is what you experience) is a state when all existing goroutines are blocked and cannot proceed on their own (ever). It doesn't matter if there are multiple existing goroutines or just a single one. If the go runtime detects a goroutine deadlock, terminates the app (there's no point letting the app hang forever, it will never recover, it's in the definition of goroutine deadlock).

---

You have a single mutex in your code which is locked in 2 goroutines: in the `main` goroutine and the one executing `f2()`.

If `f2()` reaches sooner the point to lock the mutex, the main goroutine will never be able to lock it again because no one unlocks the mutex, so then it's a deadlock. Because `f2()` will return after locking and printing, and its goroutine will end, and the only remaining `main` goroutine is blocked trying to lock `mu`. And since you used a 2-seconds sleep in `main()` between launching `f2` (as a goroutine) and  locking the mutex, you will observe this deadlock *like always*.

Note that if the `main` goroutine would be scheduled to lock the mutex first, no deadlock would occur because the `main()` function could continue to run, and once returning, the app would terminate (not waiting for `f2()` to finish). But again, due to the sleep you inserted, you will *likely never* get this outcome.

I used the phrases *"like always"* and *"likely never"* because although a sleep instruction is a good scheduling point for the goroutine scheduler, it is not a synchronization point. The runtime will schedule other goroutines to run while a goroutine is in sleep (why wouldn't it), but this is not guaranteed. Synchronization points could give you guarantee (such as channel communications, locks, `sync.Once` etc.). This is detailed in [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem).

Comment: Thanks, i know all the thing you are talk, about i still do not think this is a `deadlock` .as a deadlock there have four condition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Deadlock_handling 
maybe those Necessary conditions is only useful to detect `process` model, not `goroutine` model. since in process if you kill a thead with out release the lock. os will that part